# SQL Server unique column ID's

Tags: sql-server

I am working on an application that we will be using to maintain our database dictionary (description of each column in each table) and would like to build a "Refresh" function that can go to the database and get the updated column list/names.

What I'm having issues with is when a column is renamed/moved, I would like to track if there is way to update the database with the new details. I tried using the `Column_ID` from `syscolumns`, but this changes when the column is moved so seems to be an arbitrary number.

Is there any unique ID that SQL Server generates for a column that doesn't change?

My alternative is to add the new column and mark the old one as removed.

Thanks

Comment: There is no syntax to move columns. SSMS drops and recreates the whole table if you do that.

Comment: Thanks, i thought that would be the case. I just wanted to see if there was maybe a unique item that is assigned to a column that i could check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you store the description in the column's description property.  Then when the column is updated the developer would be responsible for updating this.

I wrote a web font-end to this over 10 years ago.... I could send you the code if you want? Looked like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That is what i ended up doing. (Using vb.net within our current software). I think this ends up being the best way to solve as it's then stored within the database and using the existing functionality.
If you would like to send the code it would be appreciated as it might show me a better way to achieve it (better coding?)

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new column and mark the old one as removed.

[edit]

I thought that what SQL server deleted the table and create it in the first place, and after your question I went to investigate:

If you mark the option of "Prevent saving changes that require table re creation" (in Options -> Designers -> Table and database designers) and then create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testTbl](
    [colA] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [colB] [smallint] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and even insert some values:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.testTbl
VALUES ('text1', 12)
,('text2', 22)
,('text3', 32)
,('text4', 42)
,('text5', 52)
```

And then run the code from above you will get:

```
SELECT c.object_id, OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) AS OBJECT_NAME
    ,c.NAME AS COLUMN_NAME
    ,t.NAME AS DATA_TYPE
    ,c.max_length AS MAX_LENGTH
FROM sys.all_columns c
INNER JOIN sys.types t ON t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
WHERE object_name(c.object_id) = 'testTbl'
```

You will get the following values:
[image]

If you try to do now the following changes (in the table designer)you will find out that all require drop and re create from the database:
Change a NULLABLE column to non-nullable
change non-nullable column to a nullable
(which is to be expected; those changes require the columns to move around the page)
change the datatype of a column (nchar(10) to more or less, smallint to tinyint or int)
but if you want to change the column from B to C, SQL can manage it, and the results would be:

[image]

The object id refers to the table id, and therefore the table stayed with the same object id.

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer not to have have the extra columns and have gone down the route of adding it into the extended properties function in SQL. This allows me to have the details visible within my application and SQL server manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this... its a composite of two queries:

This will get you the list of coumns inside a table:

```
SELECT c.object_id, OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) AS OBJECT_NAME
    ,c.NAME AS COLUMN_NAME
    ,t.NAME AS DATA_TYPE
    ,c.max_length AS MAX_LENGTH
FROM sys.all_columns c
INNER JOIN sys.types t ON t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
WHERE object_name(c.object_id) = 'TableName'
```

You can generate a HashCode of the column name and combine it with `object_id`... which should be unique unless the column name changed

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately sometimes the column names do change which is the problem i'm fighting.